# Boot problem in lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have an old msi u123 set up with lubuntu running 15.10. It works fine, but on each boot, I end up in a Recovery menu. I can select "resume" and it boots fine. I would like to try to correct whatever causes this. I have tried to look into dmesg, but I have not found any error messages there. I have also tried to see if it spits out any error messages before the recovery menu comes up, but no luck - possibly because the error message disappears too quicky when the screen is redrawn for the recovery menu.

The last message I am able to see is "Reached target Swap"

What would be the next target? Where could I look for error messages? I have not found anything in the `/var/log/` files. Is it possible to make the recovery menu behave so that I can actually see the last messages?

Comment: check the grub menu file, maybe the entry you are booting from is recovery mode!